# How do I override OnAuthorization in net core web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Earlier I achieved something like this in asp.net

```
public class Authentication : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        } else
        {
            var authenticationToken = actionContext.Request.Headers
                .Authorization.Parameter;
            var decodedAuthenticationToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationToken));
            var usernamePasswordArray = decodedAuthenticationToken.Split(':');
            var username = usernamePasswordArray[0];
            var password = usernamePasswordArray[1];

            if (GetUsers.GetDatabaseUsers.CheckCredentials(username, password))
            {// logic}
```

Now this doesn't seem to work in net core, the goal is to read the Authorization header and de-serialize it so i can pass it to my database logic that goes something like this

```
public static bool CheckCredentials(string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                var queryCommand =
                    new MySqlCommand(
                        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username LIKE @username AND password LIKE @password",
                        databaseConnection);// more code
```

Then in my ValuesController i had something as such

```
[Authentication]
 public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {

        var returnData = string.Format("database model logic{0}",mydatabasehandler.sologic,
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnData);
    }
```

Now this code might be ugly but I hope it makes sense enough for readers to understand what I want to achieve.

The base idea for this is that it will be an API for my desktop app to communicate with a MySql database only. Let me know if I should clarify something!

Extra question, i can't seem to make IntelliSense work at all when using netcore is there a way to enable this or is it lacking because it's beta?

Comment: For your extra question, be sure you're on the latest versions of everything.  I am having no issues with intellisense.  Here are the versions of what I am running: Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3 (14.0.25431.01 Update 3), Microsoft .NET Core Tools (extensions): 14.1.21111.0, running "dotnet" at the command line, it is 1.1.0, and "dotnet --version" returns 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177

Comment: As a suggestion, a better approach would be to create an authentication middleware from this. It can create a ClaimsPrincipal based on the headers, on which authorization can be based on. In ASP.NET Core the recommendation is to *not* make a custom AuthorizationAttribute.

Comment: Also, on your intellisense issue, if you're running ReSharper v10.x, you'll likely need to upgrade to the latest version that has .net core support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use custom middleware as an MVC filter to accomplish this.
This was announced in [ASP.NET Core 1.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/) (see the section on Middleware as MVC filters).

Here is some example code based on your example:

First, create your custom middleware to do the work:

```
public class MyCustomAuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public MyCustomAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        string authoriztionHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        if (authoriztionHeader != null && authoriztionHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
        {
            var encodedUsernamePassword = authoriztionHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();
            var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            var usernamePassword = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUsernamePassword));
            var seperatorIndex = usernamePassword.IndexOf(':');
            var username = usernamePassword.Substring(0, seperatorIndex);
            var password = usernamePassword.Substring(seperatorIndex + 1);

            if (GetUsers.GetDatabaseUsers.CheckCredentials(username, password))
            {
                // your additional logic here...

                await this.next.Invoke(context);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        }
    }
}

public static class MyCustomAuthenticationMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyCustomAuthentication(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<MyCustomAuthenticationMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Then, create the pipeline class to use the middleware:

```
public class MyCustomAuthenticationMiddlewarePipeline
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMyCustomAuthentication();
    }
}
```

Finally, on your action method, add the filter:

```
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(MyCustomAuthenticationMiddlewarePipeline))]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var returnData = DoSomeWork();
    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i have a base to understand it better then i could with the msdn docs.

Comment: Just found this, and wanted to offer another suggestion - you can use Policy based authorization which I belive is recommended approach.  This article has good example (about half way down): https://code-maze.com/custom-authorize-attribute-aspnetcore/