# What replaces the OnAuthorization method in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm having trouble finding an answer to this, I just keep getting references to the old way of doing it.

In Framework projects I'm referencing `System.Web.Mvc` which allows me to extend the `AuthorizeAttribute`

```
public class AccessAuthoriseAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        //... do stuff ...
    }
}
```

In ASP.Net CORE I'm referencing AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute but the method `OnAuthorization` isn't there to override.

I did find [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568050/how-do-i-override-onauthorization-in-net-core-web-api) that said I **can** setup customised middleware to handle authorisations but it seems like more work and doesn't seem as neat to call - is it the only way or is there some similar `OnAuthorisation` method I can hijack?

Comment: Have you checked the docs on authorization? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39638287/7252182) answer for an example of how to implement a simple policy.

Comment: I don't actually want to use the in-built security functions other than the `Authorize` attribute that calls a method I can customise, so I think mm8's comment linking to policies might be the way to go.